# Why is it triggering a CORS error if I'm making a request from backend (PHP)?

Tags: php, ajax, cors, localhost, cross-domain

I'm being blocked by a CORS exception (Cross-Origin Request Blocked).
I know it happens when the front end tries to send a request to an external server domain (in most cases, because they won't contain a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header), however, I'm making it from a PHP script. Why does it happen?

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js?"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
json = {
    data: {
    // my data
    }
}

post_data = JSON.stringify(json);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "main.php",
       data: post_data,
       contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

main.php

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
        
if (!isset($_SESSION["ML_ACCESS_TOKEN"])) {
    $_SESSION["REFERER"] = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
        
    header("Location: ".AUTH);
    exit;
} else {
    unset($_SESSION["REFERER"]);
}

if (isset($_POST["data"])) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

    $request = new Request;

    $url = // external url
    $headers = // headers
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $json = json_encode($data);

    $response = $request->post($url, $headers, $json);

    print_r($response);
}
```

I expected it to make the request and print the response in the index page. I'm using a localhost server, Apache2 and Ubuntu.
Is it because I have not directly *redirected* index to main? When I make a post to main, does the browser actually think *index* is making the request? If so, how could I make this request? When i execute main.php, it works just fine.

**EDIT 1**

All files, index.html, as well as main.php are located in a project folder in /var/www/html, hence being the same domain, right?

Entire error message:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.domain.com/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 302.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.domain.com/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

**EDIT 2**

Actually, the request triggering an error is not the one stated in main.php, I'm sorry. This file contains the request I want to make, however the system detects there's not a session token and redirects the user to auth.php to generate it. The first step to generate a token is to redirect the user to api.domain.

auth.php

```php
$auth_url = "https://api.domain.com/authorization";
$auth_data = array(
    "response_type" => "code",
    "client_id" => $this->getClientId()
);

$url = $auth_url."?".http_build_query($auth_data);

header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

Also, there's the current notice in /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Tue May 09 15:04:04.359422 2023] [php7:notice] [pid 26978] [client 127.0.0.1:60066] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/html/project/request.class.php on line 82, referer: http://localhost/project/index.html
```

And I've also tested it on Chromium:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.domain.com/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123' (redirected from 'http://localhost/project/main.php') from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

**EDIT 3**

The basic execution of the program is that `index.html` imports `index.js`, which sends a post request to `main.php`. When the main file checks that there's not an active session, it redirects to `auth.php` and then it's the one responsible for redirecting the user `domain.com` to generate a token. It must be a redirect because the user needs to log in their platform and i would redirect back.

I have tested executing each of the mentioned files when there's not an active session and here's what I've got:

- index (HTML/JS): sends post to main, which redirects to auth, which attempts to redirect to domain.com and **fails**.
- main (PHP): redirects to auth, which redirects to domain.com **successfully**.
- auth (PHP): redirects to domain.com **successfully**.

So the problem here is the communication between my frontend and backend. My guess is that the browser somehow interprets that index itself is redirecting to domain.com and hence blocks it through CORS policy.

Main.php is responsible for making post requests to the API i'm using, which receives data from the frontend.

Why would it be the case? Should I not be making the post request in the first place?

Comment: The error is happening when the front-end is calling the back-end, not when PHP calls the external URL.

Comment: @Barmar How so? If it's under the same domain (localhost)?

Comment: Those errors don't mention main.php at all. Are you sure it's this piece of code that causes them? Do they go away if you comment out the Ajax call?

Comment: Is `https://api.domain.com/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123` the value of `$url`?

Comment: @GuyIncognito I'm sorry, I edited the post with more information. But yes, they go away when do it.

Comment: Ok well yes, if you redirect the Ajax call to domain.com then it's a CORS request. You have to do in auth.php the same thing as in main.php, make the request to domain.com with PHP and send the response back to the frontend.

Comment: @GuyIncognito But that's what I'm doing! Ajax is calling main.php that calls auth.php, which making a request to domain.com for authentication.

Comment: This would be much easier if you showed complete code samples instead of tiny fragments. If main.php redirects to auth.php with `header()` and auth.php redirects to domain.com with `header()` then that's exactly equivalent (from CORS point of view) of making an Ajax request to domain.com directly from the frontend.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Alright! It makes sense. I updated the main.php snippet that actually redirected to auth.php, and indeed it uses `header()`. I tried redirecting from index.js to main.php using `window.location.href = "./auth.php"` and it seems to work. I also changed index.html to index.php and checked the session directly in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Guy Incognito,

> If main.php redirects to auth.php with header() and auth.php redirects to domain.com with header() then that's exactly equivalent (from CORS point of view) of making an Ajax request to domain.com directly from the frontend.

That said, I managed to find two possible solutions:

- Redirect index.js to main.php using `window.location.href = "./auth.php"`;
  or
- Rename index.html to index.php and check the session at the start of the page, as follows:

```php
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION["ML_ACCESS_TOKEN"])) {
    $_SESSION["REFERER"] = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

    header("Location: ".AUTH);
    exit;
} else {
    unset($_SESSION["REFERER"]);
}

?>
```

Observation: I was using "REFERER" session variable since $_SERVER's "HTTP_REFERER" was not a reliable source since it's not always present.